# Cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error as

> Cannot find table 0.

I tried every solution for this but not able to solve it. Kindly help. My code is given below.

```
public void BG()
{

    DataTable dtDetails = null;
    string acadamicyear = ddlacadamic.SelectedValue;
    string Class = ddlclass.SelectedValue;
    string batch = ddlbatch.SelectedValue;
    string Status = ddlstatus.SelectedValue;
    dtDetails = objdal.GetEnqToGrid(acadamicyear, Class, batch, Session["branch"].ToString(), Status);
    if (dtDetails.Rows.Count > 0 && dtDetails != null)
    {
        gridadmission.DataSource = dtDetails;
        gridadmission.DataBind();
        lblmessage.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "No records";
        lblmessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
        gridadmission.DataSource = "";
        gridadmission.DataBind();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: At which row is the error raised?

Comment: If you already tried every solution..

Comment: What does `objdal.GetEnqToGrid` do? Have you checked whether `Session["branch"]` holds a value?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `DataTable` from `GetEnqToGrid` method. In this method you are filling `DataSet` and returning `DataTable` at position 0 which may not have filled. So you need to check if `DataSet` contains table than return it.

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
 //return table;
```